# Creating a combined single barplot or histogram from two different charts with bars side by side for years 1 & 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, histogram, geom-bar

I have disease scores for a lot of trees with % dieback/ infection readings taken in two consecutive years. I can create a histogram in `ggplot2` in `r` for each year, but how do I create a side-by-side bar plot showing the readings for each year side by side with ranges e.g. 0-10, 10-20, 20-30% up to 100% infection on the x axis?

I create a simple dataframe with two readings for each year:

```
diseaseyear1 <- c(20, 30, 40, 50, 30, 20, 60, 85, 45, 32, 20, 40)
diseaseyear2 <- c(30, 35, 42, 45, 25, 70, 65, 90, 40, 25, 35, 50)
totaldisease <- tibble(diseaseyear1, diseaseyear2)
totaldisease
#I can plot year 1
quartz(10, 5)
year1 <- ggplot(totaldisease) +
  aes(x=diseaseyear1) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10) +
  labs(title = "Disease Year 1",
       y = "count", x = "% of disease") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 10, family = "GillSans"))
#I can also plot year 2
year1 <- ggplot(totaldisease) +
  aes(x=diseaseyear1) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10) +
  labs(title = "Disease Year 1 & 2",
       y = "count", x = "% of disease") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 10, family = "GillSans"))

#but how can I combine these two histograms (or bar plots) as side by side bars in one chart?
```

[image]

Comment: You need a `dodged` bar plot or maybe some `facet_*`? In your example it should be `diseaseyear2` for the second, right?

Comment: I can do facet_grids and position_dodge but I need to know how to treat the dataframe in ggplot2. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to first convert our data to a long format. This way, we can better plot the data.

```
 totaldisease %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(names_to = "dis", values_to = "val",
                      cols = 1:ncol(.)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(val, fill=dis))+
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10)+
  labs(title = "Disease Year 1 & 2",
       y = "count", x = "% of disease") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 10, family = "GillSans"))
```

Result

[image]

If you need it dodged

```
totaldisease %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(names_to = "dis", values_to = "val",
                      cols = 1:ncol(.)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(val, fill=dis))+
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10, position = "dodge")+
  labs(title = "Disease Year 1 & 2",
       y = "count", x = "% of disease") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 10, family = "GillSans"))
```

[image]

Comment: You would think it was a simple thing to do, when you consider a simple example sales data year on year comparisons etc. Thank you!

Comment: how do i tweak this to greyscale colours for the bars? e.g. dark grey and light grey?

Comment: Not on PC. Just add `scale_fill_manual` somewhere and put the colors you want in the `values` (it may be named something else) argument. Also, please consider marking answers with a tick if they solved the question. Thanks. @David Cracknell

Comment: Thanks @NelsonGon. Tick applied.